# Workflow Foundation: Asynchronous operations (lengthy network I/O)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, workflow-foundation

I have to create an application that will be started a few times per day (it's non - interactive).

To operate, it needs LARGE amounts of data from the Internet (megabytes) via a rather slow connection, so the WCF service calls take quite some time.

At the same time, it needs to perform local calculations and has a sophisticated initialization process.

So, what I want to do is to create a workflow that asynchronously fetches the data (takes a few minutes) while already initializing / calculating locally.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker_methods(v=VS.100).aspx) component for each async operation - one for the calculations and one for the data download.

My suggestion would be to use one thread for each operation.  After you start each thread, call [thread.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) one each thread to wait for each thread to finish.

e.g.

```
Thread[] workers = new Thread[2];
workers[0] = new Thread(dataDownloader.Fetch);
workers[1] = new Thread(calculator.DoComplexCalculations);

foreach(Thread t in workers)
{
   t.Start();
}
foreach(Thread t in workers)
{
   t.Join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the async classes of your wcf service (using the commandlinetool). If you run these async methods, they return immediatly and call a callback delegate when they have finished. This way you are free to do all your calculations while you wait